# What are good algorithms to keep consistency across multiple files in a network?

Tags: c, replication, consistency

What are good algorithms to keep consistency in multiple files?

This is a school project.  I have to implement in C, some replication across a network.

I have 2 servers,

**Server A1
Server A2**

Both servers have their own file called "data.txt"

If I write something to one of them, I need the other to be updated.

I also have another scenario, with 3 Servers.

**Server B1
Server B2
Server B3**

I need these do do pretty much the same.

While this would be fairly simple to implement. If one, or two of the servers were to be down, When comming back up, they would have to update themselves.

I'm sure there are algorithms that solve this efficiently. I know what I want, I just don't know exactly what I'm looking for!

Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is known as the '[CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)', which defines three properties that a distributed system can have:

- Consistency: Reading data from the system always returns the most up-to-date data.
- Availability: Every response either succeeds or fails (doesn't just keep waiting until things recover)
- Partition tolerance: The system can operate when its servers are unable to communicate with each other (a server being down is one special case of this)

The CAP theorem states that you can only have two of these. If your system is consistent and partition tolerant, then it loses the availability condition - you might have to wait for a partition to heal before you get a response. If you have consistency and availability, you'll have downtime when there's a partition, or enough servers are down. If you have availability and partition tolerance, you might read stale data, or have to deal with conflicting writes.

Note that this applies separately between reads and writes - you can have an Available and Partition-Tolerant system for reads, but Consistent and Available system for writes. This is basically a master-slave system; in a partition, writes might fail (if they're on the wrong side of a partition), but reads will work (although they might return stale data).

So if you want to be Available and Partition Tolerant for reads, one easy option is to just designate one host as the only one that can do writes, and sync from it (eg, using rsync from a cron script or something - in your C project, you'd just copy the file over using some simple network code periodically, and do an extra copy just after modifying it).

If you need partition tolerance for writes, though, it's more complex. You can have two servers that can't talk to each other both doing writes, and later have to figure out what data wins. This basically means you'll need to compare the two versions when syncing and decide what wins. This can just be as simple as 'let the highest timestamp win', or you can use vector clocks as in [Dynamo](http://db.cs.pitt.edu/courses/cs3551/11-1/handouts/10-1.1.1.115.1568.pdf) to implement a more complex policy - which is appropriate here depends on your application.

Comment: If you're storing updates, be careful about what happens in split brain scenarios - make sure your system continues to satisfy your consistency constraints even if you have these pending update buffers. Distributed algorithms are non-trivial in the extreme :) You may also find this helpful reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and how [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DropBox#Technology) works.

Answer (score 0):

With every write on to server A, fork a process to write the same content to server B. 
So that all the writes on to server A are replicated on to server B. If you have multiple servers, make the forked process to write across all the backup servers.